# RecyclerView defaults to showing the last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with two different items.

The first position should show a set of buttons while the rest of the items show details about a specific contact.

This is the adapter code

```
class CustomersAdapter(private val context: Context, private val customersListener: CustomerListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val contacts: ArrayList<Contact> = ArrayList()
    private var lastPosition = -1
    private val colorGenerator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL

    companion object {
        const val ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT = 1
        const val ITEM_TYPE_BUTTONS = 2
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_BUTTONS) {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_group_buttons, parent, false)
            GroupViewHolder(v)
        } else {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_customer, parent, false)
            ViewHolderContact(v)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder.itemViewType == ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT) {
            val contact = contacts[position - 1]
            (holder as ViewHolderContact).bind(contact)
        }
        showAnimation(holder.itemView, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return contacts.size + 1
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0) ITEM_TYPE_BUTTONS
        else ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT
    }

    private fun showAnimation(viewToAnimate: View, position: Int) {
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left)
            viewToAnimate.animation = animation
            lastPosition = position
        }
    }

    interface CustomerListener {
        fun onCustomerClicked(contact: Contact)
    }

    inner class ViewHolderContact(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(contact: Contact) {

            itemView.icon_image.visibility = View.GONE
            itemView.icon_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            itemView.tv_text.text = contact.name.firstChar()
            itemView.tv_customer_name.text = contact.name

            itemView.tv_customer_progress.text = "${contact.profileCompleteness}% completed"

            itemView.progress_customer.progress = contact.profileCompleteness

            val icon = itemView.icon_profile.background as GradientDrawable
            icon.setColor(colorGenerator.getColor(contact.name ?: ""))

            itemView.setOnClickListener { customersListener.onCustomerClicked(contacts[adapterPosition]) }

        }
    }

    inner class GroupViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    fun setContacts(contacts: ArrayList<Contact>) {
        val callback = DiffUtilCallback(this.contacts, contacts)
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)

        this.contacts.clear()
        this.contacts.addAll(contacts)
    }
}
```

But when the adapter is set, the recycler views shows the last item and I have to add something like `recyclerView.smoothScrollTo(0);` but it becomes a problem when there are more than 1000. Why does this happen? This didn't happen when I just had the contacts item and not a heterogenous recycler view.

Comment: What is the use of showAnimation function ? can you please comment it and let me know if it is still happening ?

Comment: When the itemView is added for the first time, the view slides in from left. That's it. I did comment it and try again. It didn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
if (mRecyclerView != null) {
    getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            if (position == 0) {
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the position parameter here? Is it the current position of the adapter?